# What are all these items from the Narnia books?

Tags: object-identification, the-chronicles-of-narnia, cover-art

My favourite edition of CS Lewis's *Narnia* series has covers featuring a variety of significant items from the books wrapped around by twining leaves and branches, as shown in the image below (from *The Voyage of the Dawn Treader*, although it's only the centre panel that changes from book to book):

[image]

Obviously I can identify some of these items and characters - the lamp-post, Jewel the unicorn, Susan's horn - but can we make a complete list of what they all are?

**What are all the items along the left and right sides of this book cover?**

Comment: There's some sort of animal on the [left hand side](http://tinyurl.com/zz6cuej)

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the edit!

Comment: You're very welcome. Don't forget that you can always find [alternative editions (and their covers)](http://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/3349054-the-voyage-of-the-dawn-treader?page=2) on goodreads

Comment: the animal on the left is probably Trufflehunter the badger - http://narnia.wikia.com/wiki/Trufflehunter

Comment: Does each book in the series differ slightly in the side panel designs and images, or is the outside static with only the center panel changing?

Comment: @rosesunhill Nope: like I said, it's only the centre panel that changes; the left and right sides are identical throughout.

Comment: Missed that, sorry. I've been up all night.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Left Hand Side:

- Jewel the Unicorn - *The Last Battle*
- Yellow and Green Rings - *The Magician's Nephew*
- Trufflehunter the Badger - *Prince Caspian*
- The Magician's Book - *The Voyage of the Dawn Treader*
- Cair Paravel - *The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe* (First
  Appearance)
- Lucy's Cordial - *The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe*
- The Dawn Treader - *The Voyage of the Dawn Treader*

Right Hand Side:

- Peter's Sword and Shield - *The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe*
- Bell and Hammer from Charn - *The Magician's Nephew*
- Susan's Bow and Arrow - *The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe*
- Reepicheep The Mouse - *Prince Caspian*
- The Lantern/Lamppost - *The Lion, The Witch and The Wardrobe*
- The Serpent/Lady of the Green Kirtle - *The Silver Chair*

Also, interwoven throughout are Toffee Apples from the tree in the garden in *The Magician's Nephew.*

The four corners are:

- Top Left: Jadis (The White Witch)'s Dagger
- Top Right: Susan's Horn
- Bottom Left: Aslan
- Bottom Right: Glimfeather the Owl (*The Silver Chair*)

I have this edition of the books, and it was the one I grew up with so I was able to look in better detail than the picture provided. This is also not the first time I have looked at them for hours deciding what I thought they all were.

Most of these are clear, but there are a couple that I am not 100% certain of, so I will outline my reasoning.

The serpent could be a dragon or sea serpent from *The Voyage of the Dawn Treader*, but the *Silver Chair* reference seems more likely as it was a more significant character, and matches closer with the illustration in the book.

Glimfeather, is to my recollection the only named owl with a speaking part.

The White Witch's dagger is important in both *The Lion, The Witch and the Wardrobe* and *The Voyage of The Dawn Treader*, and I can't think of another dagger of such significance.

Again, the most significant book in any of the books would be The Magicians Book from *The Voyage of the Dawn Treader*.

Comment: Lucy also had a dagger, but I think you are right that the White Witch's dagger was much more significant.

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but what makes you say that the badger is Trufflehunter from _Prince Caspian_, rather than Mr Badger from _The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet They were beavers, not badgers

Comment: @Izkata Oh yes! Good reason. Somehow, I've never noticed that before. I've always thought of them as being the same species and somehow ‘connected’ because of it. <blush>

Comment: There are also apples on the bottom-left.  The dagger could be Lucy's, that she got with the cordial (just thinking out loud).

Comment: Good, thorough answer. Just two quibbles: I think the top-left dagger is more likely to be Lucy's than the White Witch's (because that's a better parallel to Susan's horn on the top right), and the apples could instead/also refer to the opening scenes of *Prince Caspian*.

Comment: @Martha Also Jadis' *knife* (not dagger) is made out of stone (and looks that way), and that one pictured looks like metal.

Answer (score 3):

The apples are from *Prince Caspian*. The four Pevensie children land in overgrown ancient Cair Paravel and the apple orchard has overgrown. Apples are all they have to eat for several meals.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, the castle is Cair Paravel, the castle with the four thrones.  There's Susan's Bow and arrows, Peter's sword and shield, and the ship on the side is the Dawn Treader herself.  The upper left corner is Lucy's dagger. There is also Lucy's cordial made from the fire flower.  The mouse may be Reepicheep, and there's a badger head.  That's all I can see right now.

The dragon could possibly be the one the Eustace changes into during *"The Voyage of the Dawn Treader"*  Alternatively, it could be the Sea Serpent from the same book.

There's also a badger head, and possibly Eustace's diary.

Comment: Yes ... and? There's a lot more items than that, if you look more closely :-) (Also, ***Percy***?)

Comment: @randal'thor percy, peter, same difference. Also, was going off the old picture, my poor eyesight, and my memory. :P

Comment: Badger is Trufflehunter most likely.

Comment: I see Susan's horn, possibly Lucy's dagger, the Lantern of Lantern Waste, Glimfeather the Owl, and Jewel the Unicorn. There may be more (I think I see Reepicheep under Susan's bow) but the resolution, and my eyesight, start giving me problems.

Comment: Under Peter's shield is the bell from Jadis' Hall.

Comment: The dragon Eustace turns into has claws and wings

Comment: +1 to this. But I think I'll have to accept razethestray's answer instead, sorry :-)